# Connect to MySQL from Broadleaf framework community

Tags: java, broadleaf-commerce

Could you please show me how to connect broadleaf framework (current version 5.2) to MySQL, i try to follow this [link](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/getting-started-tutorials/switch-to-mysql-tutorial) but i do not see build.properties in project, and other links i found was too old.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that, that specific tutorial is a bit out of date. The correct version is under the 'Database Configuration' section of the docs: https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/database-configuration/mysql. This has instructions for Windows, Linux and macOS.